# How to set random concated item in where clause in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to generate random unique username. I have two table syllable1 and syllable2. Both have two column id, word. I am choosing random word from both table and concat them. Now I want to check this concat name NOT IN my user table Like

```
SELECT CONCAT((SELECT word FROM syllable1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1), (SELECT word FROM syllable2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)) WHERE NOT IN (SELECT username FROM user)
```

Before WHERE clause it works fine to generate a random name. Please help out in second step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer having the subqueries in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT CONCAT(s1.word, s2.word)
FROM (SELECT word FROM syllable1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) s1 CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT word FROM syllable2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) s2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM user u
                  WHERE u.username = CONCAT(s1.word, s2.word)
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You must put the WHERE clause in an outer query:

```
SELECT t.username FROM (
  SELECT CONCAT(
      (SELECT word FROM syllable1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1), 
      (SELECT word FROM syllable2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) 
    ) username
) t
WHERE t.username NOT IN (SELECT username FROM user)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5s9qJdui98L1AQVSS5cTV2/0).